# Load resources from a working directory rather than from app directory

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, assets, resourcedictionary

In my WPF application I'm using a `ResourceDictionary` to store paths for all assets. Here's the example:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime">
    ...
    <BitmapImage x:Key="SomeKey"
                 UriSource="/MyWPFApp;component/Assets/Images/SomeImage.png" />
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

No matter how I start the application, it will try to load images (and other assets, such as fonts, videos and sounds) from the application directory, i.e. if my app is located at `C:\\MyApp\\MyApp.exe`, then the resources are going to be loaded from `C:\\MyApp\\Assets\\...`.

The question is: if I'm starting my app by using a shortcut from a different directory, is it possible to load assets from this folder?

For example, if I have my shortcut to app located at `D:\\Shortcuts\\MyAppShortcut.lnk`, can I somehow load assets from `D:\\Shortcuts\\Assets\\...`? I don't want to specify the absolute path for each resource inside the ResourceDictionary since it's a subject to change (i.e. shortcut could be moved to another location).

Comment: The running app doesn't "know" where the link started it was located. You might be able to work with working directory and System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Comment: @Andy how am I supposed to use this approach in WPF? Do I have to manually set that in code-behind everywhere any of the assets are used?

Comment: The path in ResourceDictionary is usually fixed as relative path to the executable file. IMHO, it won't fit your requirement. Said that, as a workaround, you can get the path to shortcut which invokes the executable file at runtime by including the path in the shortcut's arguments and obtaining it with Environment.GetCommandLineArgs method.

Comment: Thanks @emoacht, I'll look into this.